# How do you say ‘-crat’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The Esperanto translation of ‘bureaucrat’ is ‘burokrato’ and the Esperanto translation of ‘democrat’ is ‘demokrato’, and so it would seem that ‘-krato’ would be the translation of ‘-crat’ (defined in Merriam-Webster as a ‘noun combining form’), but it doesn’t seem to exist in the standard English-Esperanto dictionaries, nor does PIV recognize ‘krato’. So, is ‘krato’ a de facto suffix in Esperanto, like I suppose ‘atizi’ (for ‘atize’) is?

Answer (score 4):

Neither *-krat-* nor *-atiz-* are morphemes in non-technical Esperanto*, they are parts of the root, which is borrowed as is and without further segmentation from the point of view of Esperanto grammar.

*There may be exceptions in language for special purpose, but I don't know these very examples. But e.g. in biology there are specialised suffixes like *-ed-* ([*bovedoj*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bovedoj)) or *-ac- ([*cetacoj*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetacoj)). However, like in ethnic languages these affixes are not productive outside their narrow scientific field.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the endings of Esperanto roots look the same because they were imported as whole roots into Esperanto from words which were originally made up of parts in another language. This is the case with *burokrato* and *demokrato*. This doesn't mean, though, that the rules of the source languages apply to Esperanto. There is no suffix "-krato" in Esperanto.